# How to convert composite attribute E/R diagram in UML diagram?

Tags: database, uml, entity-relationship

I have the **entity** `Person`, which has the **attribute** `"address"`. The attribute address, has the **attribute** `"street name"` and `"zip code"`.

Now, I am asked to make a `UML Diagram`, but I have no clue on how to make this when I have an attribute of an attribute.

I have this already:

> Person
>
> - ID << PK >>
> - Address: string

But what should I do with "street name" and "zip code", now? They are part of "address", but how do I state that in UML?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the schema is this one:

[image]

And after you have the question to model the storage, you have at least two choices : two tables with an association or to embed Adress in Person table.

And the last point is how to model annotation in UML ... I do not know an official answer. Maybe three options exist : use a comment to describe that, define one ste

Comment: apologize, zipCode has to be private and an id has to be added to Address (which is misspelled :( )

Comment: But address is an attribute, not an entity... so how can I use a table for it in UML?

Comment: and the end of the sentence is missing : Maybe three options exist : use a comment to describe that, define one stereotype per annotation, use an OCL constraint (I am not sure about this last suggestion)

Comment: Depending if you are speaking about classes or tables. Something which have to attributes can be a DataType or a Class ... But you can store it in Person table with Embedded and Embeddable annotations.

Comment: Or the simplest solution is to add two attributes to Person : street name and zip code ...

Comment: `adress` should be `address`

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Can you give an example? So I can store address as an attribute in my "person" class, and then what? What do I do with zip code and street name? Make a new class for them? Inheritance? What? I am confused.

Comment: Right sorry for the spelling,

Comment: I'd further stereotype `id` with `<<PK>>`.

Comment: It was for JPA (persistence in Java) are you in this case ?

Comment: @Siyah `address` is an attribute inside `Person` and it is of type `Address`. It's called a role name.

Comment: I am afraid that <<PK>> is not define in UML norm is it ? , if not it is needed to precise the published profile which defines it ...

Comment: Yes, I get that, Thomas... but what do I do with zip code and street name then? That's what the whole question is about. What to do with attributes of attributes?

Comment: First a Address class : \@Embeddable
 public  class Adress with the attributes, then a Person class with an attribute     \@Embedded
     private Adress adresse ; like that Adress data are store in Person table.

Comment: Sorry man, I can't understand you. I just have a composite attribute and I want to know HOW that's converted in a UML diagram.

Comment: In which language are you coding ? For me, in UML a composite type is only a DataType or a Class. DataType are not so often use so I suggested to create a class Address and an association between Person and Address. If your UML tool provide DataType element, then create a DataType named Address with two fields and add an attribute of type Address in Person.

Comment: @granier Stereotypes are meant to be "invented" by users. The whole UML Profile stuff is based on stereotypes.

Comment: @Kilian it is what i understood from stereotypes also, but when one is defined we should say which UML element is extended, how it is extended then a profile has to be defined. For me, stereotypes are more than a "tag"